# regex character and value from 0 to 99999

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a regex that matches the letter v or V and any 5 digits number. 
For example:
V35145
v12453

A value with characters after the letter V will generate an error:
V125aa
v35as4

thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post your attempts.

Comment: [This question is off-topic (#1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Christian. You'll have better success getting an answer if you follow the steps found in the help article [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think the primary reason for the down votes and claims to this question being off topic is that is feels like you're breaking [category 3 off-topic questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." Though you don't say if this is for homework, personal or professional reasons, you seemed to show little self-solving initiative, which is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

`^[Vv][0-9]{5}$`

```
^ means starts with
[Vv] - means we want a letter, either v or V
[0-9] - means we want a digit
{5} means we want 5 of them
$ means ends with
```

Comment: This ensures a string a 5 digits. OP *seems* to want 1 to 5 digits.

Comment: @erip, I dont think so, seems to want `any 5 digit[s] number`

Comment: `value from 0 to 99999`

Comment: The OP also seems to have little experience with RegEx, so it is probably worth giving an explanation of the expression parts as well as a link to something like regexr.com and/or regexper.com.